# Confusion in targets iPhone/iPad in Xcode

Tags: xcode, target, compiled

I have a question that may look stupid for some of you=)
I have a project with 2 targets lets it be "game" and "game-iPad"
in summary/devices i choosed iphone for first target and ipad for second
I have 2 sets of nib files related to this targets, unfortunately when i try to test my game on iPad the "game" project compiled in device. So I see small window on ipad with ability to scale it to ipad sizes and bundle display name shows that "game" target was compiled. Of cause window of "game-iPad" target has iPad's sizes so it obvious that wron' target is compiled=)
how can I compile exact target on idevice("game-iPad")?
thanks for all of you for Ur attention and help=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the Device in the AppDelegate.m's :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

with something like that

```
 CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

....

```
else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

And target your nib in there with something like this:

```
[[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
```